# Creating adjacency matrix for BFS

Tags: c++, graph, adjacency-matrix, breadth-first-search

I am given a input file that contains numbers like this:

3   (searching for value 3 in graph)

5 (number of vertices in graph)

0 0 (vertex 0 has value has value 0)

2 (add 2 edges from vertex 0)

1 ( add an edge from vertex 0 to vertex 1)

2 ( add an edge from vertex 0 to vertex 2)

1 1 (vertex 1 has value 1)

2 (add 2 edges from vertex 1)

3 (add an edge from vertex 1 to vertex 3)

4 (add an edge from vertex 1 to vertex 4)

2 2 (vertex 2 has value 2).......

I want to create an adjacency matrix using the given numbers in the file, but I am unsure of how to do this. How would I make sure I'm just filling the matrix with either 0's or 1's depending on whether or not there is an existing edge? I don't think I can just read in each file one-by-one because not all of the lines detail info about the edges. Any insight would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since you know almost immediately what the size of the matrix is, you can allocate a adjacency matrix of the required size, then go through the file, adding edges as you encounter them. An outline of the code might look something like:

```
std::ifstream in;

// Read the target and number of nodes.
int target;
int num_nodes;

in >> target >> num_nodes;

// Whatever matrix data type you are using.
matrix adj_matrix(num_nodes, num_nodes);

// Process each vertex.
for (int i = 0; i < num_nodes; ++i) {
    int node;
    int value;
    in >> node >> value;

    // Figure out how many edges the vertex has.
    int num_edges;
    in >> num_edges;

    // Process each edge and add it to the matrix.
    for (int j = 0; j < num_edges; ++j) {
        int other_node;
        in >> other_node;

        // Add the dependency both ways to the matrix.
        adj_matrix[node][other_node] = true;
        adj_matrix[other_node][node] = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your matrix `Edges` is filled with zeros, you can do something like that:

1. Read the first number and store the value somewhere (I don't
   understand what the first number is for, actually).
2. Read the second number and store it in `n`.
3. While there is no end of line do lines 4..8
4. Read the number and store it in variable `v` (number of
   vertex)
5. Read the number and store it in `Values[v]` (value of current
   vertex)
6. Read the number and store it in `e` (number of edges from
   `v`'th vertex.
7. For i from 1 to e do 8.
8. Read `v1` and put `Edges`[v,v1]=1 (and maybe E[v1,v], if E has to be symmetric).